# Adding a URL within a Text object in Swift

Tags: swiftui

I am battling with layout or padding or something similar in SwiftUI.

What I want is a view containing a sentence that reads "A website named StackOverflow exists for peer help" where StackOverflow is a URL that the user may tap and navigate to the StackOverflow website. The code below works however ...... the button with the link appears out of line. I want it to read like a sentence without line breaks or padding etc.

All ideas welcome, but it is not as simple as embedding in an HStack.

```
var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("something)")) {
                
                let urlStackOverflow: URL = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com“)!
                    
             
                Text("A website named") 

                Button(action: { UIApplication.shared.open(urlStackOverflow) }, label: {
                        Text("StackOverflow“).bold()
                    })

                Text("exists for peer help“)  
          }}}
```

Comment: Explain why HStack doesn't work for you.

Comment: HStack with (padding:0) for example still doesn't show the sentence flowing "A website named StackOverflow exists for peer help" but odd spaces. I just want the sentence to appear as text but a link for StackOverflow, as in A website named <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> exists for peer help, for example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with a single `Button` and multiple `Text`s added together as views.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let urlStackOverflow = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("something")) {
                Button(action: { UIApplication.shared.open(self.urlStackOverflow) }) {
                    Text("A website named")
                    + Text(" StackOverflow ")
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    + Text("exists for peer help.")
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Limitations:

1. The entire text would be clickable.
2. Multiple links are not supported.

Comment: Right, so the whole text object is the link, and the impression that it is just StackOverflow is given by the blue text visual cue. That would work for a single link in the "sentence", but not for two links in the sentence. Thanks though.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that there would be two links in the question. This should work for the problem in the question that you've posted.

Comment: Only one line and one URL in the question, yes, I was just trying to keep the question as succinct as possible whilst at the same time looking for a generic solution. Thanks again